Calculating a Due Date based of criteria and returning a due date, excluding weekends
I have three columns on my SharePoint list:

Request Type
Date Received
Due Date

There are SLAs surrounding the request type which drive when the item is due.
For ease of simplicity:
Request Type (let's just call them A, B, C, D, E, F, G, and H)

A = due 10 business days from date received
B = due 10 business days from date received
C = due 15 business days from date received
D = due 15 business days from date received
E = due 30 business days from date received
F = due 30 business days from date received
G = *has no required due date (field should appear as blank in the Due Date column)
H = *has no required due date (field should appear as blank in the Due Date column)

I have been able to build the IF / OR logic like this:
=IF(OR([Request Type]="A",[Request Type]="B"),[Date Received]+10,IF(OR([Request Type]="C",[Request Type]="D"),[Date Received]+15,IF(OR([Request Type]="E",[Request Type]="F"),[Date Received]+30,"")))

But now I want to figure out how to fold Weekday function in the Due Date column to exclude the weekends on those counts.
Any advice?

You can utilize WEEKDAY function of SharePoint which gives week day number based on your given date.
So based on above description your formula should look as below:
=IF(OR([Request Type]="A",[Request Type]="B"),
    [Date Received] + 10 + INT((10 + WEEKDAY([Date Received] - 1) - 1) / 5),
IF(OR([Request Type]="C",[Request Type]="D"),
    [Date Received] + 15 + INT((15 + WEEKDAY([Date Received] - 1) - 1) / 5),
IF(OR([Request Type]="E",[Request Type]="F"),
    [Date Received] + 30 + INT((30 + WEEKDAY([Date Received] - 1) - 1) / 5),
"")))

INT((X + WEEKDAY([Date Received] - 1) - 1) / 5) part calculates how many weekends will occur during the period and adds extra days to account for those weekends. This ensures that the due date will not fall on a weekend.
Official Documentation

WEEKDAY function

